# Post a form with Ajax to ASP.NET MVC Controller

Tags: .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When I click on the link "Foo", I hit the break point in the LogOn action but username is always null. I don't understand why.

```
<a class="jqselect" id="myId" href="#">Foo</a>    
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOn", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "fooForm" }))
{
    <input type="text" id="username"/>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".jqselect").click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Account/LogOn',
                type: "Post",
                data: $('#fooForm').serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.success) {
                    }
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(string username)
{
    Console.WriteLine(username);
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to give it a name:

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
```

You can actually drop the `id` and just have the name and the controller method will recognize it.

You can also use a model if you want and you can code it like:

```
@Html.TextboxFor(m=>m.Username)
```

where your model is defined as:

```
public class LogOnModel {
    public string Username {get;set;}
}
```

and your method defined as:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel input)
{
}
```